# Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php

I'm able to upload up to 10 images via a file upload form but when I try to upload more than 10 images PHP throws this error:

> Warning: exif_imagetype(): Filename cannot be empty

I've edited my PHP.ini file. In there I have:

```
post_max_size = 40M
upload_max_filesize = 40M
max_file_uploads = 20
```

I've checked my phpinfo page and it confirms these settings are set. I've restarted Apache many times.

I know I'm not over the max filesize limit because I created some test images that are just 1kb each and they won't upload, yet I'm able to upload large images of many MB if I upload fewer than 10 files.

My form looks like this:

```
<form id="photos_form" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"><input type="hidden" name="temp_id" value="20170511-073423-2820394"><section><h1>Add Photos</h1><div id="photos_wrap"><label for="photos">Select photos of your item to upload:</label><br><button id="choose_photos_btn" type="button">Add photos</button><input id="photos" name="photos[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" ></div><button id="photos_submit">Upload selected photos</button><div id="photos_preview"></div></section></form>
```

It's posted via XHR

```
 // Photos form submit
$('body').on('submit', '#photos_form', function (e) {
        //disable the default form submission
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#photos_submit').addClass('uploading').text('Uploading...');

        //grab all form data
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);



        $.ajax({
            url: 'lib/upload-photos',
            dataType: 'html',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
                $('#photos').val('');
                $('#photos_submit').hide();
                $('#photos_wrap').removeClass('error');
                $('#photos_wrap .photos_error, #photos_preview .deleted, #upload_errors').remove();

                $('#photos_preview').append(data);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error uploading photos");
            }
        });


        return false;
    });
```

My PHP looks like:

```
if ($_SERVER ['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if (isset($_FILES ['photos'])) {
            $num_pics = count($_FILES ['photos'] ['name']);
            echo 'num pics is ' .$num_pics;
        }
}
```

and says 
    num pics is 1

a print_r of $FILES gives:

```
Array
(
[photos] => Array
    (
        [name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [type] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [tmp_name] => Array
            (
                [0] => 
            )

        [error] => Array
            (
                [0] => 4
            )

        [size] => Array
            (
                [0] => 0
            )

    )

)
```

How can I upload more than 10 images?

Comment: Do you see that error code is 4?

Comment: Yep I saw that. It means no file was uploaded. But why?

Comment: var formData = new FormData('#photos_form'); i think it should be form id

Comment: When I use that code, I get the error: TypeError: Argument 1 of FormData.constructor is not an object.

Answer (score 0):

I had some Javascript which was overridding the PHP.ini settings. That was the problem.